# IPTables rules not working, while previously they did..?

Tags: iptables

For a school project I am developing a router based on Ubuntu Server 16.04 which will use open-source monitoring software. The night before the client had internet access. I've changed my development location from home to work so I had to change the dns accordingly (from home isp to work isp) and to my surprise the client did not have internet access anymore.

The following ruleset is enabled:

*changing the FORWARD parameter to ACCEPT instead of DROP solves the problem, but due to security reasons I'd rather not do that.*

```
iptables --flush
iptables -- table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j
```

If someone could clarify why I am experiencing this while the same set of rules did their work in the previous network?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, somehow I did not have ufw enabled. Which made it impossible for the client to get access. I'll leave this post for future references.

Best of luck!